# GitLab setup email

Tags: sendmail, gitlab

I'm trying to setup the email sender in GitLab.

I've installed postfix as adviced in the guide but when I register a new user the email is not sent.

I've tried configuring the `smtp_settings.rb` with configurations of one of my windows mail servers but when I restart gitlab the `GitLab Unicorn web server` fails to start.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Are there any error messages in `logs/unicorn.stderr.log` or `logs/unicorn.stdout.log`?

Comment: I've only `4982 TID-owgcdpthc INFO: Sidekiq client using redis://localhost:6379 with options {:namespace=>"resque:gitlab"}` into `unicorn.stdout.log`

Comment: @FezVrasta Were you found the solution?

Answer (score 1):

check your file /home/git/gitlab/config/environments/production.rb (if your running on production, wich is standard)

There you can change your sendmail settings. Perhaps you should try to remove the -t parameter, wich fixed it for me!

Comment: Thanks but no luck :(